# How to use TKPROF utility along with syntax and parameters?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to use TKPROF utility along with syntax and parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just type "tkprof" at the OS command prompt it lists its parameters and their meaning like this:

```
> tkprof
Usage: tkprof tracefile outputfile [explain= ] [table= ]
              [print= ] [insert= ] [sys= ] [sort= ]
  table=schema.tablename   Use 'schema.tablename' with 'explain=' option.
  explain=user/password    Connect to ORACLE and issue EXPLAIN PLAN.
  print=integer    List only the first 'integer' SQL statements.
  aggregate=yes|no
  insert=filename  List SQL statements and data inside INSERT statements.
  sys=no           TKPROF does not list SQL statements run as user SYS.
  record=filename  Record non-recursive statements found in the trace file.
  waits=yes|no     Record summary for any wait events found in the trace file.
  sort=option      Set of zero or more of the following sort options:
    prscnt  number of times parse was called
    prscpu  cpu time parsing
    prsela  elapsed time parsing
    prsdsk  number of disk reads during parse
    prsqry  number of buffers for consistent read during parse
    prscu   number of buffers for current read during parse
    prsmis  number of misses in library cache during parse
    execnt  number of execute was called
    execpu  cpu time spent executing
    exeela  elapsed time executing
    exedsk  number of disk reads during execute
    exeqry  number of buffers for consistent read during execute
    execu   number of buffers for current read during execute
    exerow  number of rows processed during execute
    exemis  number of library cache misses during execute
    fchcnt  number of times fetch was called
    fchcpu  cpu time spent fetching
    fchela  elapsed time fetching
    fchdsk  number of disk reads during fetch
    fchqry  number of buffers for consistent read during fetch
    fchcu   number of buffers for current read during fetch
    fchrow  number of rows fetched
    userid  userid of user that parsed the cursor
```

A typical usage would be:

```
tkprof tracefile.trc myoutputfile.txt explain=myschema/password sys=no sort=exeela
```

For more info see the [Performance Tuning Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#i4640).

Comment: Which one is commonly used sorting parameter?

Comment: It depends what you are interested in, but EXEELA is common as it shows the slowest SQL (in elapsed time) first.  Usually I run it once, take a look at the summary at the end, and then re-run sorting on whatever value looks suspiciously large.

Comment: I get `-bash: tkprof: command not found` error on Mac. Is there any way to run this command on mac? Thanks.